# Black screen changing views in xcode 4,5

Tags: iphone, ios, view, xcode4.5

I have the following code:

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PlaceViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet PlaceViewController *placeview;
}

- (IBAction)passPlace:(id)sender;
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
@synthesize placeview;

- (IBAction)passPlace:(id)sender{
    self.placeview = [[[PlaceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self presentViewController:placeview animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**PlaceViewController.h**

```
@interface PlaceViewController : UIViewController{

}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end
```

**PlaceViewController.m**

```
@implementation PlaceViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Change!!!!!");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And the storyboard:

http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1233/screengy.png

I have no idea that what I'm doing wrong because when I change view, the PlaceViewController is a black screen with a blue status bar.

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: if you are using `storyboard`, why you need to give `initWithNibName`. you can link from your `MapViewController` to `PlaceViewController` in your `storyboard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using storyboard... go into the Storyboard Editor and in the Attributes Inspector, set an Identifier, let say "PlaceMap" (in picture “AddPlayer”)

[image]

change your code:

```
- (IBAction)passPlace:(id)sender{
    self.placeview = [[[PlaceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self presentViewController:placeview animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

with

```
- (IBAction)passPlace:(id)sender{
PlaceViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlaceMap"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
}
```

You can check alos, a very nice tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

**UPD**

that is for Navigation Controller

> [self presentViewController:placeview animated:YES completion:nil];

if you want modal... can you use:

```
newView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
//deprecated 6.0
//   [self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];
//from 5.0
[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm not using storyboard and that button is inside an annotation from MkMapView:
"UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [pinView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];"

Comment: I sow your comment: "And the storyboard:

http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1233/screengy.png"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm using the storyboard only for design views, not for buttons

Comment: Sorry for noob question but what's 'nib name'?

Comment: the name of your graphically interface.. what is the name.nib displayed in  Navigator (the file list.. left side.. )?

Comment: Do you mean the name of file? I have these [image](http://img72.imageshack.us/img72/3774/screenfiles.png)

Comment: no, you don't have nib file. You are using Storyboard... you must check my code

Comment: I have this error: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PlaceViewController 0x13fdfa30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key storyboard.'"

And I put the name "PlaceViewController" into class name form of Identity Inspector

Comment: (I change the "PlaceMap" name from your example code for "PlaceViewController")

Comment: Change the name in identity Inspector and your code to "PlaceName".. to avoid "collision" with PlaceViewController.. If you il have the same error, open this controller (PlaceViewController) and right click on "File Owner" and check if you have connected any wrong property or outlets

Comment: It works, the problem was the "collision" with class name. Lot of thanks TonyMkenu

Comment: Glad to help you. Now is tour turn ...  Help me accepting my answer :)